# Want to write HTML Content on a WebPart for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

In developing Sharepoint Webpart, if I need to add HTML Content to the output of my Web Part, right now I do it like this  :

```
   this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<html content>");
```

If I need to output a large HTML Content with Data in it, I need to instantiate a lot new Literal Contents then there is a problem, that it will make my process slow and memory consuming.

Please tell some alternatives to this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a visual webpart where you get to use the WYSIWYG designer and if it needs to be deployed in a Sandboxed environment you can download one from the Power Tools extension.

Oh God, writing all that markup from code is a nightmare. By using a visual webpart you can make amazing looking webparts.

If you are going to use your own scripts or CSS files just create mapped folders for them and set the deployment option to their path.

Comment: Can you share a link for reading more about the Visual Webpart and the WYSIWYG designer thing.

Comment: Just google it. The best thing to do is to start with an empty SP project than add a new item and choose "visual web part". That way you can add extra features if need be. You will see a designer where you can drag and drop controls an edit the html directly and then there is a code behind page for your logic. Make sure you click on the feature section and enable it as a feature or it won't be deployed. Is this a sandboxed web part or can it be a farm soultion?

Answer (score -1):

You can approach this problem by analysing webpart rendering time by using Developers DashBoard (only in SharePoint 2010). To enable this you should use powershell code like this:

```
$svc=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$ddsetting=$svc.DeveloperDashboardSettings
$ddsetting.DisplayLevel=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::OnDemand
$ddsetting.Update()
```

When DD is enabled use this instruction to chceck your rendering time on server side:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/28/using-the-developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

You can also use monitored scopes (SPMonitoredScope) to check parts of your code which can take most part of rendering.